# Google Analytics Event Tracking doesnt work

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

the event tracking is not working. There is the code for Google Analytics in the head:

```
<script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX');
    gtag('event', 'submit', {
    'event_category': 'Form',
    'event_label': 'abgeschickt',
    });
</script>
```

Here is a picture of the event settings of Google Analytics in German:

[image]

Here is the HTML-code of the event button. Its a contact form and looks this way:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Dein Name *"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input name="email" id="email" placeholder="Deine E-Mailadresse *"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Deine Telefonnummer"/>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-12"> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="9" id="message" placeholder="Gib hier deine Nachricht ein *"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="submit" value="Nachricht senden"/>
</div>
</form>
```

The event tracking is not working, but why? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: How do you know its not working?

Comment: Because I tested it. There is no conversion in GA. The contact form is triggered, mail also arrives, but no tracking in GA.

Comment: and you looked in the real-time report and waited 48 hours to check the standard report?

Comment: Yes, i looked in the real-time report but not waited 48 hours...does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a redundant comma in your script after 'abgeschickt' 
It should look like that

```
gtag('event', 'submit', {
    'event_category': 'Form',
    'event_label': 'abgeschickt' // no comma after last property
    });
```

Comment: Thank you! 

Other problem: GA tracks something, but its wrong. GA said that 14 conversions are received, but we didnt get an e-mail via the contact form...

What's wrong?